# Figure caption alignment screwed when using line break

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, line-breaking

I am having trouble with figure captions when I need a manual line break.

```
\documentclass[A4]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang,small,it]{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Single line no problem.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption[Content]{Sketching out variants for a new glass plate based installation.\\%
Unless specified, sizes are in cm.}
\label{fig:sketches_plate_arrangements}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The second figure caption is left aligned instead of centered. (in my actual setup it is a bit more to the right, and the second line is at least properly indented, but still the caption is way too much left).

[image]

---

Well, since you closed the question for unknown reasons, here is my answer. The idea is to use the `margin` parameter of `captionsetup`. If `captionsetup` is used without "float type" option and inside the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` block, it only applies the settings for one particular occurrence.

```
\documentclass[A4]{book}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang,small,it]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{dissem_Modell2_hires.png}
\captionsetup{%  settings just for this caption
  margin = 70pt
}
\caption[Content]{Sketching out variants for a new glass plate based installation.%
Unless specified, sizes are in cm.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because the layout is horrible. The first line gets way too long, and the second line only has one or two words left. Semantically it's much better to put the second sentence on a new line.

Comment: Adding `\centering` after the line break partly fixes the problem, but then the second line is not left aligned with the first line.

Comment: @egreg - the question you link to has an accepted answer which doesn't work. caption is still glued to the left margin.

Comment: @EmitTaste The explanation of how the caption's typesetting takes place is what matters.

Comment: @tohecz Actually my thesis class was using the caption package. I have added the line. This doesn't change. It seems that with `hang`, it ignores the line break and calculates the width of the caption based on the text width as if there was no line break, reaching the full `\textwidth`, and therefore sticking to the left margin.

Comment: I managed to set up `captionsetup` to make the linebreak superfluous (using `margin`). Now __all that I need__ is to isolate that setup so it is only applied to _one_ particular figure block. Right now, it changes the global settings!

Comment: @tohecz Hanging left with the first line. I understood the problem (the caption package has a bug which means it calculates the line width irrespectable of the Break). Now I only need to figure out how to use `captionsetup` locally (without destroying my global settings)

Comment: Well, you're quite brave calling something a bug in a package just because it doesn't work the way _you_ would like it to. IMO it's a bug to use manual line-break in a situation like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind manual tweaks, you can use `\oalign`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Single line no problem.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption[Content]{\oalign{Sketching out variants for a new glass plate based installation.\hfil\strut\cr\strut Unless specified, sizes are in cm.\hfil}}
\label{fig:sketches_plate_arrangements}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't mind manual tweaks right now, as it is probably one in thirty cases that needs it. I like both your and @egreg's answers. I'll accept yours because I have only one tick I can make. If I encounter more cases, I might reside with the `breakcaption` macro.

Answer (score 5):

You can exploit `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{varwidth,calc}
\usepackage[hang,small]{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\breakcaption}{\@dblarg\emit@breakcaption}
\long\def\emit@breakcaption[#1]#2{%
  \expandafter\caption\expandafter[\expandafter\emit@removeafter#1\\\@nil]{%
    \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth-\widthof{\figurename\space\thefigure:\space}}
    #2
    \end{varwidth}%
  }%
}
\def\emit@removeafter#1\\#2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\breakcaption{Single line no problem.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\breakcaption[Short caption]{%
  Sketching out variants for a new glass plate based installation.\\
  Unless specified, sizes are in cm.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\breakcaption{%
  Sketching out variants for a new glass plate based installation. 
  Something else to fill more lines\\
  Unless specified, sizes are in cm.}
\label{fig:sketches_plate_arrangements}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you see, you can use `\breakcaption` as a substitute for `\caption` in all cases, with also the optional argument (where `\\` could even be used, but it would be removed together with everything following it). I assume that in the list of figures you don't want the text after the forced break, as it makes sense only in the real caption.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That command is real magic to me :) but it works indeed as I want! Yes, I used short captions for the table of contents indeed. I'll have a look into the `varwidth` package to understand what's going on here.

Comment: This has been very helpful to me, i am trying to modify it so the second line that breaks, does not have an indent, i'd be glad if you could help

Comment: @SofiaMouseti Just use the regular `\caption` command.